# Tomcat6 webapp not deploying on amazon Ec2

Tags: web-applications, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, tomcat6

I've been wrestling with this for quite some time. I have a webapp (jasperserver) that i've successfully uploaded to my tomcat6 server. Here it is:

```
root@ip-172-31-46-109:/var/lib/tomcat6/logs# cd /var/lib/tomcat6
root@ip-172-31-46-109:/var/lib/tomcat6# ls
common  conf  logs  server  shared  webapps  work
root@ip-172-31-46-109:/var/lib/tomcat6# cd webapps
root@ip-172-31-46-109:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps# ls
jasperserver  jasperserver.war  ROOT
root@ip-172-31-46-109:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps# cd jasperserver
root@ip-172-31-46-109:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/jasperserver# ls
blank.htm  cal  errorPage.htm  index.htm  j  jasperreports-flash-5.0.1.swf  jpivot  META-INF  scripts  themes  wcf  WEB-INF
```

I know tomcat6 is working because when i go to `http://localhost:8080` I can see the tomcat6 default index. However, `http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/`  is displaying a 404!!

It seems like i've done everything right here...does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thats the problem with the tomcat server. The solution is to delete the ROOT folder and rename your jasperserver app folder to ROOT, restart the tomcat server and then see what happens. It should work fine.

Comment: I tried that, however, something in my code is still looking for the original folder path (/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/jasperserver) instead of (/var/lilb/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT) how can I change that?